# Querying for huge number of keys from rails mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a rails app running on mongo. There is one Document that I need to query to perform a big calculation. The list of keys is huge like 50 plus.

I will be writing the calculation method in the model itself.

Since the number of keys is huge if I keep assigning the value of key to a local variable and use them, I would have to create 50 plus local variables. 
It would look like follows:

```
def get_score
  record = Model.last
  a1 = record['k1'],
  a2 = record['k2'],
  a3 = record['k3'] 
  ##---so--on 50 plus keys
  #formulae. Where I will be using the a1...a50 variables to calculate.
end
```

This would make the method unnecessarily look huge and wont look efficient at all.
Is there a way where I can add these keys into a file or hash and map and call those keys on the model at a once?

Comment: `hash = record.attrributes.slice('k1', 'k2','k3', ...)` or if the keys really are sequential `hash = record.attrributes.slice(Array.new(50){|n| "k#{n+1}"})`

Comment: The calculation is not plain addition. Again here I have to call each value like ```hash[k1]+(hash[k2]+ hash[k3])/hash[k8]```. Is there anyway to make it more efficient than this?

Comment: Make what more effecient then what? This question is so vague is bordering on farcical

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated hash accesses, you could do:

```
hash={'a1'=>1,'a2'=>2}
eval (1..2).map { |i| "@a#{i} = hash['a#{i}'];" }.join
```

This gives you `@a1` and `@a2`.

I can't figure out how to create local variables programmatically. You can write to a [binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Binding.html) but not to the local scope it seems.